# Swift background work

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development and I'm using Swift in my current project.
I'm trying to achieve something similar I did in Android. I'm trying to run a background service when the app is closed/minimised that will get executed every 2 seconds to keep the user informed that the app is still running in the background and checking for status with the server.

How can I achieve that? I've tried using the "background fetch" method but it doesn't get executed every 2 seconds.

The background service will run no longer than 5 minutes if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. What you can do is, call a service in **applicationDidEnterBackground** that lets your server know that your app is in background or killed(You will get very less time for this to get executed, approx. 3-5 sec.).

Answer (score -1):

An Android app like the one you described will likely drain the device’s battery prematurely. This is the simple reason why Apple has restricted background execution to a clearly defined set of tasks:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that record audio content while in the background
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

This list is taken from Apple’s official description of background tasks: [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).